# From HH:MI:SS to HH:MI in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to do a query where the input is an hour in the HH24:MI:SS format, I want to return HH12:MI format, I tried the following:

```
select to_timestamp ('08:00:00', 'HH12:MI');
```

But it's returning me this

```
0001-01-01 08:00:00-04:27:44 BC
```

How could I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want `to_char()`, not `to_timestamp()`:

```
select to_char('08:00:00'::time, 'HH12:MI');
```